# Оборот "если...то"

Tags: сложное-предложение

Почему в одних случаях "то" входит в главное предложение и в схеме выделяется квадратной скобкой, например: [], и (если  ), [то  ] , а в другом случае входит в придаточное и выделяется круглой скобкой: [], (что(если    ), то   ). Имеются в виду конструкции типа: и если...,то; что если...,то .   А ещё в учебнике Львова написано, что союзы "если не...то"в сложносочиненном предложении выражают градационные отношения. Разве  союзы если не... то могут быть в сложносочиненном предложении? Считала, что только в  сложноподчиненном.Получается, например, предложение Если не солнце светит, то дождь идет - сложносочиненное? Почему так? Объясните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание ЕСЛИ...ТО может относиться к сочинительным или подчинительным союзам.

1. Среди сочинительных союзов выделяют **группу двойных (градационных) союзов**, среди них есть союз **ЕСЛИ НЕ...ТО.**

**Можно посмотреть:** [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf), стр. 108. Также: http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/451 (здесь приведена схема для градационных союзов.

***Если не солнце светит, то дождь идет.*** Это сложносочиненное предложение, по смыслу оно соотносится с сочинительным союзом ТО...ТО (значение чередования)

2. Среди подчинительных союзов также есть двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, он используется в СПП с **придаточными условными**. Первая часть союза относится к придаточной части, а вторая – к главной.
3. **В сложных конструкциях** (при встрече сочинительных и подчинительных союзов) СПП с союзом ЕСЛИ...ТО может рассматриваться как единое целое. Если сочинительный союз И относится ко всему СПП, то оно, вероятно, должно полностью заключаться в квадратные скобки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, особенно за ссылку на учебник, обязательно воспользуюсь. Ответ многое мне прояснил